# When recyclerview is filtered image inside recyclerview does not changed

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which shows me the list of words and on right side I have bookmark button for each view. Everything works fine but if there is already bookmarked word and if I filter the rycyclerview the image for bookmark does not change. Here you can see in these screenshots:

Before filtering everything is ok as you can see: 3 words are marked

[image]

But when I filter the recyclerview another 3 words are beeing marked in that position actually they are not marked

[image]

Here is my code for getting bookmark word and comparing with others and marking if they match :

Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT title FROM bookmark WHERE title IN (SELECT title FROM words)", null);

```
    while (c.moveToNext()){
        String title = c.getString(0);

        if (title.equals(holder.wordsName.getText().toString())){
            holder.wordsFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_black_24dp);
            holder.wordsFav.setTag("clicked");
        }
         else if (!title.equals(holder.wordsName.getText().toString())){
             holder.wordsFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border_black_24dp);
         }
    }
```

And here is the code for filtering :
In adapter :

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return wordsFilter;
    }

    private Filter wordsFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Words> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){

                filteredList.addAll(wordsListFull);

            }else {

                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (Words words: wordsListFull){
                    if (words.getWord().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                        filteredList.add(words);
                    }
                }

            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            wordsList = new ArrayList<Words>();
            wordsList.clear();
            if (wordsList != null){
                wordsList.addAll((List) results.values);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

And in fragment :

```
searchWords.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() != 0) {
                    clearTextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    clearTextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            searchWords.setText("");
                            clearTextBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    clearTextBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                wordsAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: post the code where you are filtering the list (on typing in search box)

Comment: add code for filtering see edit

Comment: no need to check again if title is equal or not equal in else part. and get the title from the list, not from holder then compare the strings

Comment: I already tried comparing from list and without else statement but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the image to grey if that particular title is not in the bookmark.

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT title FROM bookmark WHERE title IN (SELECT title FROM words)", null);

        while (c.moveToNext()){
            String title = c.getString(0);

            if (title.equals(holder.wordsName.getText().toString())){
                holder.wordsFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_black_24dp);
                holder.wordsFav.setTag("clicked");
            }else{
             holder.wordsFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
            }
        }
```